¿Cómo trabajar con 2 arrays de obj para que genere un tercer array (con .map), que sea igual a [cod array1, ΣpropiedadArray2], en JavaScript?
Estoy tratando de crear con 2 arrays un tercero que tenga las cuentas y la sumatoria de la cuenta (con filter), para después sumar con reduce y completar el array resultante...
Los arrays iniciales
 const array1= [
        {
            "cod_cuenta": "C-A-A0-001",
            "nombre_cuenta": "EMPALMES PROVISIONALES",
            "monto_cuenta": 2992017
        } ]
   

    const array2 = [
        { 
        "descripcion_OC": "ARRIENDO BAÑO QUÍMICO CON LAVAMANOS",
        "glosa": "JUNIO-AGOSTO",
        "codigo_cuentaCosto": "C-A-E0-001",
        "nombre_cuentaCosto": "INSTALACION DE FAENAS % 100",
        "unidad": "Mes",
        "cantidad": 3,
        "moneda": "UF",
        "precioUnitario": 2.25,
        "prec_unit_desc": 2.25,
        "descuento": 0,
        "sub_Total": 200121.3,
        "cant_Recibida": 2.97,
        "monto_Recibido": 198217.01,
        "devolucion": 0,
        "estado_linea_recepcion_OC": "Abierta"
    }
        ]

acá la función
        const sumas = array1.map(
            x => [x.cod_cuenta, array2.filter(
                y => y.array1.cod_cuenta === y.array2.codigo_cuentaCosto)
                .reduce(
                (acc,curr) => acc + curr.array2.sub_Total,0)
          ];
        );
        console.log(sumas);

y no funciona.

Cuál sería la salida esperada?

un array con dos propiedades, [cod cuenta, suma de los valores de los codigo de cuenta]

Creo que tienes una confusión, cuando haces un map o un filter, ejemplo: array.map(x=> //algo) ese x es el argumento de la función. En ambos casos (map y filter) internamente se realiza una iteración y ese x corresponde al "ítem" en cada iteración

x será el ítem 0 en la primera iteración
x será el ítem 1 en la segunda iteración
y así sucesivamente

Entonces cuando haces
//                     |- Esto no tiene sentido-|
//                     v                        v
array2.filter(y => y.array1.cod_cuenta === y.array2.codigo_cuentaCosto)

Primero porque y es un item de array2 (ya estas dentro del array) y luego porque tú quieres comparar "algo" de x con algo de y, y en tú código solo llamas a y
array2.filter(y => x.cod_cuenta === y.codigo_cuentaCosto)

Mismo caso en el reduce, donde el primer argumento es el acumulador y el segundo el item
Así te debería funcionar
const sumas = array1.map( x => [x.cod_cuenta,
                array2.filter(y => x.cod_cuenta === y.codigo_cuentaCosto)
                .reduce((acc,curr) => acc + curr.sub_Total,0)
              ]);

